# apache - rewrite dynamic url into static url on addon domain is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am working on seo of my website,after reading some articles i found out about seo friendly urls so i decided to change all dynamic url into static url.
for eg: most of the urls are like `www.abc.com/final.php?id=1&name=name-of-file` but i want to change the urls into static urls like `www.a.com/name-of-file/1`

I tried to edit .htaccess file but its not working.

my `.htaccess file`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule final/id/(.*)/name/(.*)/ final.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: A general note: if possible you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last means for those who do _not_ have access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers).

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ final.php?id=$2&name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: what is the error pelase comment/remove other conflicting rule then try.

Comment: there is no error,but it does n't change the url into static one

Comment: According to this rule when you call `www.abc.com/name-of-file/1` internally it will rewrite to `www.abc.com/final.php?id=1&name=name-of-file` are you sure you are doing that. redirecting and rewriting are different things.

Comment: ohh now I get it,i also want to redirect `www.abc.com/final.php?id=1&name=name-of-file` to `www.abc.com/id/1/name/name-of-file` actuall I was assuming rewriting and redirecting are same ,thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+final\.php\?id=([^\s&]*)&name=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/? final.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: its working,but my css is not working on that page,i think its all because of $_GET variables

Comment: Use absolute links for css, or add in the html head: `<base href="/">`. Because you change your URL and your relative root.

Comment: how can I append previous page url,suppose I have results on search page with url  `www.abc.com/x/y/query='dfg'` and when I click on any one result it should open `www.abc.com/x/y/name-of-file/id-num` instead of `www.abc.com/name-of-file/id-num`

Comment: I do not understand the question. My answer to your original question. For another issue, add a new question

Comment: If you want to change a link in an HTML page, you must change in your html or your program.